# How to increase load(aka request per second) in Karate-gatling test

Tags: karate

I have a set of karate gatling tests, but the request per second is not going up after 6-8 request/sec.
My target is to achieve something around 80-100req/sec.

Machine configuration:

2 CPU Cores

16GB Memory

---

Versions in pom.xml

Gatling Maven Plugin: 3.1.2

karate-gatling : 1.2.0.RC3

karate-apache : 0.9.6

karate-junit5 : 1.2.0.RC3

---

```
Gatling setup looks something like this

val scn1 = scenario("someScenario").group("homePage"){
    feed(csvfeeder).exec(karateFeature("PATH_TO_FEATURE_FILE"))
}
...
<Some more snc definition>
...
    
setUp(
      scn1.inject(
        constantConcurrentUsers(18).during(3600 seconds)).protocols(protocol),
      ),
      scn2.inject(
        constantConcurrentUsers(16).during(3600 seconds)).protocols(protocol),
      ),
      scn3.inject(
        constantConcurrentUsers(6).during(3600 seconds)).protocols(protocol),
      ),
      scn4.inject(
        constantConcurrentUsers(8).during(3600 seconds)).protocols(protocol),
      ),
      scn5.inject(
        constantConcurrentUsers(12).during(3600 seconds)).protocols(protocol),
      )
    ).maxDuration(1800 seconds);
```

Across all the scenarios(5)/karate.feature file calls around 50 different graphql APIs.

> More than 60% of the requests the 95th percentile is about 5 seconds
> to complete.
>
> Few(2-3) APIs the 95th percentile is > 15seconds.
>
> For all other APIS 95th percentile is < 1 second.

---

I have tried 2 things to speed up the tests, but both have failed.

1. I tried increasing the concurrentUsers numbers by 3-4X but that doesnt seem to work.
2. Based on other similar SO question ([how to load more requests per second in karate gatling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63178702/how-to-load-more-requests-per-second-in-karate-gatling)) Added a `gatling-akka.conf` in `src/test/resources/gatling-akka.conf` also didnt improve the performance.

   akka {
   actor {
   default-dispatcher {
   type = Dispatcher
   executor = "thread-pool-executor"
   thread-pool-executor {
   fixed-pool-size = 200
   }
   throughput = 20
   }
   }
   }

---

The Machine CPU usage pattern

The CPU usage goes till 100% then comes down to 15% then gradually raised to about 98-100% then again comes back to 15-20%.

Comment: if the linked answer did not help the only thing that will get us anywhere is to follow this process: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue - and clear examples of how others have done it is in the linked answer itself